# Exercise enumeration

Tags: macros, numbering, lists, enumerate, exercises

In order to make it easier to write hand-in assigments, I want to create two environments `Subexc` and `subexc`, where I can write the entire exercise down before starting. `Subexc` is supposed to be run with an argument, specifying the enumeration format to be used (note that I am using the `enumerate` package). `Subexc` then saves the format in a variable `\subExcFormat` and the exercise number in a counter `subExcCounter`. When `subexc` is run afterwards, it then continues the exercise number and the format from `\Subexc`. An example:

```
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newenvironment{Subexc}[1]
{%
    \begin{enumerate}[#1]%
        \item\ignorespaces\begin{itshape}%
}{%
    \end{itshape}%
    \end{enumerate}\setcounter{subExcCounter}{\theenumi}%
    \global\let\subExcFormat#1%
    \vspace{1 mm}\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend%
}

\newenvironment{subexc}
{%
    \begin{enumerate}[\subExcFormat]%
    \setcounter{enumi}{\thesubExcCounter}%
    \ignorespaces\item\begin{itshape}%
}
{%
    \end{itshape}%
    \end{enumerate}%
    \setcounter{subExcCounter}{\theenumi}%
    \vspace{1 mm}\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend%
}

\begin{document}
\section*{Exercise 717}
\emph{In this exercise, we will prove the Riemann hypothesis.} %Text from exercise.

\begin{Subexc}{(a)} % Enumeration format of the form (a), (b), ...
  Prove that $8 + 7 = 15$. % exercise text.
\end{Subexc}
Blablabla %My answer

\begin{subexc} % No format; it will continue the format from the last section.
  Show that $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$.
\end{subexc}
Bluhbluhbluh %My answer

\begin{subexc}
   Use (a) and (b) to show the Riemann hypothesis.
\end{subexc}
Wowowow %my answer
\end{document}
```

However, I get the errors

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \endSubexc }
Illegal parameter number in definition of \subExcFormat \end{\subexc}
Undefined control sequence \begin{subexc}
Undefined control sequence \begin{subexc}
(Warning) The counter will not be printed.
```

What went wrong? :-)

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `#1` in the end part. But you can simply move the definition of `\subExcFormat` in the begin part. Using `\theenumi` is wrong: `\value{enumi}` is what you need (it's the cause of the warning, by the way).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcounter{subExcCounter}
\newenvironment{Subexc}[1]
  {%
   \gdef\subExcFormat{#1}%
   \enumerate[#1]%
   \item\itshape
  }
  {%
   \endenumerate\setcounter{subExcCounter}{\value{enumi}}%
   \par\vspace{1 mm}\noindent\ignorespacesafterend
  }

\newenvironment{subexc}
  {%
   \expandafter\enumerate\expandafter[\subExcFormat]%
   \setcounter{enumi}{\value{subExcCounter}}%
   \item\itshape
  }
  {%
   \endenumerate
   \setcounter{subExcCounter}{\value{enumi}}%
   \par\vspace{1 mm}\noindent\ignorespacesafterend
  }

\begin{document}
\section*{Exercise 717}
\emph{In this exercise, we will prove the Riemann hypothesis.} %Text from exercise.

\begin{Subexc}{(a)} % Enumeration format of the form (a), (b), ...
  Prove that $8 + 7 = 15$. % exercise text.
\end{Subexc}
Blablabla %My answer

\begin{subexc} % No format; it will continue the format from the last section.
  Show that $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$.
\end{subexc}
Bluhbluhbluh %My answer

\begin{subexc}
   Use (a) and (b) to show the Riemann hypothesis.
\end{subexc}
Wowowow %my answer
\end{document}
```

I removed also useless `\ignorespaces` commands, `\begin{itshape}` and `\end{itshape}`. I remain dubious about

```
   \par\vspace{1 mm}\noindent\ignorespacesafterend
```

that seems superfluous; just avoid a blank line if you don't want a new paragraph. Note also `\par\vspace{1mm}` rather than the inverse.

[image]